# Android : FragmentManager is already executing transactions when switching fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this error when I try to switch between 2 fragments and I do not know how to fix it :

**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:2177)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2233)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:781)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:289)
                      at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:17445)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3333)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4977)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4768)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4708)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4681)
```

**My code :**

```
transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    linearScore = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearScore);
    linearScore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        fragment_score frag_score= new fragment_score();
            switch_fragment(frag_score,"fragment_score");
        }
    });
    linearReglage = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearReglage);
    linearReglage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fragment_reglage frag_reglage= new fragment_reglage();
            switch_fragment(frag_reglage,"fragment_reglage");
        }
    });
    RoundedImageView roundedImageView =(RoundedImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.futurImage);
    roundedImageView.setImageBitmap(((Main)getActivity()).getBmImage());
    return view;
}

public void switch_fragment(Fragment fragment, String tag ){
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment,tag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

For information I have already an other tabhost in an other fragment I do not know if it is link

Thank's to reply